# Change default color react mat ui speed dial

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I have react material ui SpeedDial with default primary color. How to change color to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to SpeedDial helped:

```
<SpeedDial
        FabProps={{ size: "medium", style: { backgroundColor: "#ff0000" } }}>
/*other*/
</SpeedDial>
```